# Bar plot with two factors with gradient color in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gradient, factors

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = data.frame(time = rep(0.5:9.5, each = 10), roi = rep(1:10, 10), area = runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))
```

I would like to draw a plot including 10 bars of 10 values of `time` and `roi`. In this case, x-axis will be `roi`, y-axis will be `time`, and the values of `area` will be showed in bars with gradient color (highest = white, lowest = black). The y-axis is reversed from 0.5 top to 9.5 bottom, width of bar is 2.

The expected figure looks like
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojHTa.png).

I am looking forwards to replies and I appreciate your all helps.

Comment: Can you explain how you would draw a bar (lets say the one on top, next to `time == 0.5`) if you would do it by hand (paper + colored pencil)?

Comment: Sorry, I had a bit confuse in data frame, could you change it to
df=data.frame(time=rep(0.5:9.5,each=10),roi=rep(1:10,10),area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))

Comment: @Qaswed: I found an option called "yAxisReversed" by ggplot2.barplot here http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplot-easy-bar-graphs-in-r-software-using-ggplot2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
df=data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,each=10)),roi=rep(1:10,10),area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))

df$time <- factor(df$time, levels=rev(levels(df$time)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(y=factor(roi), x=time, fill = area)) +
  theme_minimal()  + coord_flip() +
  geom_tile(colour = "white", width = .9, height = 1) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that what I need. I love you and your answer so much. I am clapping my hands. Thank you soooooooo much.

Comment: Hi Shirin Glander, I want to decrease the width (actually the height) of bars following:

df=data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,each=10)),roi=rep(1:10,10),area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))

df$time <- factor(df$time, levels=rev(levels(df$time)))
ggplot(data=df, aes(y=factor(roi), x=time, fill = area)) +
  theme_minimal()  + coord_flip() +
  geom_tile(colour = "white", width = .9, height = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")

How can I remove the space between bars (I mean the spaces between rois).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Adjust the width and height parameter (to zero if you want no space) in geom_tile(colour = "white", width = .9, height = 1.